# sql server 2012 copy database failed between two instances on the same host

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am learning the sql server 2012 and got stuck when using the copy datase, trying to figure out why.

I created two instances on the same host, using administrator, windows authentication. 
(the default instance:iZp0w14yqtvxcmZ, the second instance: iZp0w14yqtvxcmZ\instance2, try to copy database from the default one to the second one)

It failed at the last step: execute sql server agent job.
here is the error log from windows event viewer:

```
Message: Failed to connect to server iZp0w14yqtvxcmZ.
StackTrace:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.Connect()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.TransferObjectsTask.TransferObjectsTask.OpenConnection(Server& server, ServerProperty serverProp)
InnerException-->Login failed for user 'NT Service\SQLAgent$INSTANCE2'.
```

Then I tried to add the login 'NT Service\SQLAgent$INSTANCE2' in the default instance. Then tried again and got another error:

```
Event Name: OnError
 Message: An error occurred while transferring data. See the inner exception for details.
StackTrace:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Transfer.TransferData()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.TransferObjectsTask.TransferObjectsTask.TransferExtraObjectsViaSmoTransfer()
InnerException-->Windows NT user or group 'iZp0wd5ebkvswaZ\Administrator' not found. Check the name again.
```

But the Adminitrator does exist in the computer management -> local user and groups -> group, so I don't know what to do now. NEED HELP !!!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

after two-day's struggling, I figured it out. The sql server agent service should use a domain-based account for a multi-server environment. Also that account should be able to log in and perform the job.

Comment: Omg So why the wizard allow to set sql authentication??? I think this is a bug of crappy code in my log the user agent try to log with user 'sa'. I wasted 3 hours of my life but now I will export db as script.

Comment: After ~6 hours of troubleshooting and trying every possible solution, I think your explanation is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue changing the login method to system local account.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Two instances must have the same password and open, then in this case:

> insert into [EI7-PC\SQLEXPRESS2].[MYCOMPANY].[dbo].[inventory] SELECT *
>     FROM [EI7-PC\SQLEXPRESS1].[MYCOMPANY].[dbo].[inventory] where itemno='10-0001'

The reason for the same password is unknown, this is per my experience. With two different password you may get an error about 'sa' failed to login.